# Could someone help me to understand my error on the Route?

Tags: laravel

Hey I create a personal plugin for CMS and I have a little problem (first time I use Laravel) I have a complication with the Routes can someone guide me here?

```
    [previous exception] [object] (Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\RouteNotFoundException(code: 0): Route [lon.admin.database.index] not defined. at C:\\wamp64\\www\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\UrlGenerator.php:466)
[stacktrace]


   
Route::middleware('can:lon.admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/settings', [SettingController::class, 'show'])->name('index');
    Route::post('/settings', [SettingController::class, 'save'])->name('index.save');

    Route::get('database', [DatabaseController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
    Route::post('database', [DatabaseController::class, 'show'])->name('show.save');

});



 class DatabaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the index settings page.
     *
     * @return Application|Factory|View
     */
    public function show()
    {
          return view('lon::admin.database.index', [
            'type' => 'typename',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 3306,
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'password',
        ]);
    }

    public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'type' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'host' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'port' => ['required', 'integer', 'between:1,65535'],
            'database' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        ]);

        Setting::updateSettings([
            'lon.host.'.$request->input('type') => $request->input('host'),
            'lon.port.'.$request->input('type') => $request->input('port'),
            'lon.database.'.$request->input('type') => $request->input('database'),
            'lon.username.'.$request->input('type') => $request->input('username'),
            'lon.password.'.$request->input('type') => $request->input('password'),
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('lon.admin.database.index')->with('success', trans('admin.settings.updated'));
    }
}


    @extends('admin.layouts.admin')

@section('title', trans('lon::admin.settings.title'))

@section('content')
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="{{ route('lon.admin.database.index') }}" method="POST">

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="type">{{ trans('lon::admin.settings.type') }}</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="type" name="type" value="{{ $type }}" required="required">
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="host">{{ trans('lon::admin.settings.host') }}</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="host" name="host" value="{{ $host }}" required="required">
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="port">{{ trans('lon::admin.settings.port') }}</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="port" name="port" value="{{ $port }}" required="required">
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="database">{{ trans('lon::admin.settings.database') }}</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="database" name="database" value="{{ $database }}" required="required">
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="username">{{ trans('lon::admin.settings.username') }}</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="{{ $username }}" required="required">
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="password">{{ trans('lon::admin.settings.password') }}</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="{{ $password }}" required="required">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="bi bi-save"></i> {{ trans('messages.actions.save') }}
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

I end up with an error of which I do not understand its interest. I've tried everything and really can't find it.

Thanks for any help you can give me

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow. You get an error because you don't have a route declaration with the "lon.admin.database.index" name.

```
Route::get('/settings', [SettingController::class, 'show'])->name('index');

// Replace the above line with the following line.

Route::get('/settings', [SettingController::class, 'show'])->name('lon.admin.database.index');
```

If it doesn't solve your problem, it means you added a prefix to route names. Run the `php artisan route:list` command on CLI. You can see full route names (with prefixes) in the name column of the result. By guiding CLI, you can change the route name to match the correct one.